# Apache Tomcat 8.5.4 Ubuntu 16.04 not working!

Tags: 16.04, apache2, java, ubuntu-mate, tomcat

I have installed the following distribution of Tomcat:
http://mirror.its.dal.ca/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.4/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.4.tar.gz

I have followed this instruction step by step:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

Now when I start the service, I get the following error:

```
tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-07-13 18
  Process: 31037 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAI

Jul 13 18:42:53 NewPro3D systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Applicati
Jul 13 18:42:53 NewPro3D systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 13 18:42:53 NewPro3D systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

For some reason the JRE_HOME was not getting any value- defaulted to 'user/'.
I tried the export command as well as bashrc, none of them worked.
I manually added a line to set the value of this environment variable within the setclasspath.sh .